# Optimizing looping select statements

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

So I'm currently have a database that holds survey questions and am now wanting to display the results. **Things to note:** There can be 2-6 answers per question depending on the question.

These are the tables I'm using and some example data:

```
 Table: answers_only         Table: questions_only
╔════════════════╦════════╗ ╔═════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ answer_ID (PK) ║ answer ║ ║question_ID (PK) ║ question          ║
╠════════════════╬════════╣ ╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║    65114       ║ yes    ║ ║       123       ║ Are you happy?    ║
╚════════════════╩════════╝ ╚═════════════════╩═══════════════════╝

                    Table: questions
╔════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ unique_ID (PK) ║ question_ID (FK) ║ answer_ID (FK) ║ person_ID (FK) ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
║              1 ║              123 ║          65114 ║           5521 ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

So I have a table **questions** that contains IDs (FK) to **questions_only** which holds actual questions. Here I am grabbing the top 100 questions that were answered:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT question, questions.question_ID AS question_ID 
FROM questions 
INNER JOIN questions_only ON questions_only.question_ID=questions.question_ID 
GROUP BY questions.question_ID 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC limit 100");
```

Next I go through each question and gather how many of each answer there was:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $question_ID = $row['question_ID'];

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT answer, COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
    FROM questions 
    INNER JOIN answers_only ON answers_only.answer_ID=questions.answer_ID 
    WHERE questions.question_ID= '" . $question_ID . "' 
    GROUP BY answer ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"); 
}
```

Currently the first line of code takes about 8 seconds to execute. The second part (looping through 100 select statements) is eating up around 350 seconds. So I'm looking for better ways to do this as currently it's not usable at this kind of time. Currently this code runs in the head tag of the document.

Comment: 1. Are your indexes set up on the FK's? 2. count(*) should be replaced with count(_fld_) for performance.

Comment: I just checked and I was missing some indexes on a few columns. This helped a lot actually, down to 25 seconds. Also about the count(*), I actually tried both of them and found that count(*) is about a second faster than using a column.

Comment: if you remove the order-by-clause, what timings to you get? You may need a trigger+denormalized count-field here. Currently, timings seems horrible for any real usage.

Answer (score 0):

When things like this take up a lot of time, maybe your server will time out.  In those instances, one way to solve the problem is to give the database a call with each row of output.  That is, change the strategy for getting the data into parts that will keep the connection alive and provide the user with some feedback for every second they are waiting.

A procedure that would look like that might go:

```
// get all of the question ids that matter.
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT questions.question_ID AS question_ID 
FROM questions DESC limit 100");  // or similar
// pack all of those into an array
$answerHolder = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $question_ID = $row['question_ID'];
    $answerHolder[] = $questionID;
}
// iterate through that array to get the questions that match each id

foreach ($answerHolder as $item){
// use $item in a SQL call to get the question
// as each question is obtained, print it out to display or store it for later use
}
```

A change in procedural pattern similar to this will help to keep your database connection alive and might provide enough timely feedback to keep your users interested.  Anytime that they're kept waiting for more than 10 seconds, you might want to consider providing them with some kind of progress statement to let them know that the program is working.

This approach will not be much faster, but it might keep users and systems engaged in solving the problem at hand.

Comment: Awesome advice. Definitely user feedback is key. I'm with you on that.